# Streaming data and Hadoop? (not Hadoop Streaming)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'd like to analyze a continuous stream of data (accessed over HTTP) using a MapReduce approach, so I've been looking into Apache Hadoop. Unfortunately, it appears that Hadoop expects to start a job with an input file of fixed size, rather than being able to hand off new data to consumers as it arrives. Is this actually the case, or am I missing something? Is there a different MapReduce tool that works with data being read in from an open socket? Scalability is an issue here, so I'd prefer to let the MapReducer handle the messy parallelization stuff.

I've played around with [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/) and was able to run a job on a static file accessed via HTTP, but this doesn't actually solve my problem. I could use curl as an intermediate step to dump the data somewhere on a Hadoop filesystem and write a watchdog to fire off a new job every time a new chunk of data is ready, but that's a dirty hack; there has to be some more elegant way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hack you describe is more or less the standard way to do things -- Hadoop is fundamentally a batch-oriented system (for one thing, if there is no end to the data, Reducers can't ever start, as they must start after the map phase is finished).

Rotate your logs; as you rotate them out, dump them into HDFS. Have a watchdog process (possibly a distributed one, coordinated using ZooKeeper) monitor the dumping grounds and start up new processing jobs. You will want to make sure the jobs run on inputs large enough to warrant the overhead.

Hbase is a BigTable clone in the hadoop ecosystem that may be interesting to you, as it allows for a continuous stream of inserts; you will still need to run analytical queries in batch mode, however.

Answer (score 6):

What about http://s4.io/. It's made for processing streaming data.

## Update

A new product is rising: [Storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm) - Distributed and fault-tolerant realtime computation: stream processing, continuous computation, distributed RPC, and more

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look over Esper CEP ( http://esper.codehaus.org/ ).

Comment: I am not much familiar with this field, but on first look also liked ActiveInsight (CPAL license -- requires attribution).

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo S4 http://s4.io/

It provide real time stream computing, like map reduce

Answer (score 1):

Twitter's [Storm](http://storm-project.net/) is what you need, you can have a try!

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options here.
I suggest the combination of Kafka and Storm + (Hadoop or NoSql) as the solution.
We already build our big data platform using those opensource tools, and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case sounds similar to the issue of writing a web crawler using Hadoop - the data streams back (slowly) from sockets opened to fetch remote pages via HTTP.

If so, then see [Why fetching web pages doesn't map well to map-reduce](http://ken-blog.krugler.org/2009/12/12/why-fetching-web-pages-doesnt-map-well-to-map-reduce/). And you might want to check out the [FetcherBuffer](http://github.com/bixo/bixo/blob/master/src/main/java/bixo/operations/FetcherBuffer.java) class in Bixo, which implements a threaded approach in a reducer (via Cascading) to solve this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you know the main issues with Hadoop for usage in stream mining are the fact that first, it uses HFDS which is a disk and disk operations bring latency that will result in missing data in stream. second, is that the pipeline is not parallel. Map-reduce generally operates on batches of data and not instances as it is with stream data.

I recently read an article about M3 which tackles the first issue apparently by bypassing HDFS and perform in-memory computations in objects database. And for the second issue, they are using incremental learners which are not anymore performed in batch. Worth checking it out [M3
: Stream Processing on
Main-Memory MapReduce](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6228181&tag=1). I could not find the source code or API of this M3 anywhere, if somebody found it please share the link here.

Also, Hadoop Online is also another prototype that attemps to solve the same issues as M3 does: [Hadoop Online](https://code.google.com/p/hop/)

However, [Apache Storm](https://storm.incubator.apache.org/) is the key solution to the issue, however it is not enough. You need some euqivalent of map-reduce right, here is why you need a library called [SAMOA](http://samoa-project.net/) which actually has great algorithms for online learning that mahout kinda lacks.

Answer (score 0):

Several mature stream processing frameworks and products are available on the market. Open source frameworks are e.g. Apache Storm or Apache Spark (which can both run on top of Hadoop). You can also use products such as IBM InfoSphere Streams or TIBCO StreamBase.

Take a look at this InfoQ article, which explains stream processing and all these frameworks and products in detail: [Real Time Stream Processing / Streaming Analytics in Combination with Hadoop](http://www.infoq.com/articles/stream-processing-hadoop). Besides the article also explains how this is complementary to Hadoop.

By the way: Many software vendors such as Oracle or TIBCO call this stream processing / streaming analytics approach "fast data" instead of "big data" as you have to act in real time instead of batch processing.

Comment: Just to add some more information: See my blog post for a detailed comparison of [when to use a stream processing framweork vs. a product][1].

In summary, you can **use these tools to process data while in motion**. Nevertheless, you can (or have to) still store them somewhere. Therefore, these frameworks and products can also be combined with Apache Hadoop (just for storage or also for processing by running one of the frameworks on Hadoop). The slides also discuss this in more detail.


  [1]: http://www.kai-waehner.de/blog/2015/10/25/comparison-of-stream-processing-frameworks-and-products/

Answer (score 0):

You should try Apache Spark Streaming.
It should work well for your purposes.