# Hadoop Streaming job vs regular jobs?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

What's the difference between Hadoop Streaming job and regular java job. Is there any advantage of using Hadoop streaming over the latter.

One more thing ,I am using **mapreduce** API (i.e, new API) and I heard   that streaming only available with deprecated **mapred** API. Is it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217850/streaming-data-and-hadoop-not-hadoop-streaming?rq=1
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598422/is-it-better-to-use-the-mapred-or-the-mapreduce-package-to-create-a-hadoop-job?rq=1

Comment: please try google.com before posting for quick answers.

Answer (score 7):

Hadoop streaming is advantageous for those cases when the developer do not have the much knowhow of Java and can write Mapper/Reducer in any scripting language faster.

When compared to custom jar jobs, a streaming Job would also have the additional overhead of starting a scripting(Python/Ruby/Perl) VM. This leads to a lot of inter-process communication, resulting in reduced efficiency of the jobs in most of the cases.

Using Hadoop streaming brings with it restrictions on the input/output formats. There are times when you would like to create custom input/output formats, using custom jars would be the natural choice. Also using Java one can over-ride/extend many of hadoop's functionalities to one's need/choice.

Quoting from an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569009/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-running-a-job-in-hadoop-using-various-languages):

> Hadoop do has capability to work with MR jobs created in other
>   languages - it is called streaming. This model only allow us to define
>   mapper and reducer with some restrictions not present in java. In the
>   same time - input/output formats and other plugins do have to be
>   written as java classes So I would define decision making as
>   following:
>
> - Use Java, unless you have serious codebase you need to resue in Your MR job.
> - Consider to use python when you need to create some simple ad hoc jobs.

As for streaming only available for `mapred` API, it doesn't make sense. While using streaming mappers/reducers are written in another languages, so no point worrying about which API hadoop internally will use in order to execute them.

Comment: where could i find more details. Some links would be helpful

Comment: consider using google, it is a great website, here you have the first hit if you type hadoop streaming: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/streaming.html

Comment: even this answer would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873077/streaming-or-custom-jar-in-hadoop/6889756#6889756

Comment: I encountered a problem with streaming using mapred API. This is when tried to create a custom input format. When extended from TextInputFormat of new API, got an exception saying MyCustomeInputFormat is not mapred.TextInputFormat. I changed it to use old API and the problem got solved. Not sure if it will create any compatibility issues